# Continuity of a function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, bounded-variation

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function of bounded variation. Then it is well known that it has right and left limits everywhere and only jump discontinuities. Set $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x+)$, the right limits of $f$. Suppose $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $\tilde{f}(\lambda+)=\tilde{f}(\lambda-)=\tilde{f}(\lambda)$ (i.e. a point of continuity for $\tilde{f}$). Is it also true that $\lambda$ is a point of continuity of $f$?

$EDIT:$ This is wrong. In fact, consider the function $\chi_{(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)}$. It has bounded variation and its "right continuous" version is just $1$ everywhere, which is continuous at $0$ while the original function isn't. The problem lies in that I assumed somehow that functions of bounded variation only have jump discontinuities, which is wrong! They might have so-called removable discontinuities, where the limits from the left and right at a point agree but they do not agree with the value of the function at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Addendum**

There is a potential flaw in the original proof (below) which assumes that convergence to right-hand limits is uniform. Here is a different proof.

Any function of bounded variation has at most countably many jump discontinuities. There are two possibilities.

(1) There are finitely many jump discontinuities in some open neighborhood of $\lambda$. In this case, there is an interval $(\lambda - \delta, \lambda + \delta)$ where $f$ is continuous except possibly at $\lambda$. For $x \neq \lambda$ we have $f_R(x) = f(x+) = f_L(x) = f(x-) = f(x).$ By  hypothesis $f_R$ is continuous at $\lambda$ and, therefore, $f_R(\lambda-) = f_R(\lambda+)$.

Thus $$f(\lambda-) = \lim_{x \to \lambda -}f(x) = \lim_{x \to \lambda -}f_R(x) = f_R(\lambda-) = f_R(\lambda+) = \lim_{x \to \lambda +}f_R(x) = \lim_{x \to \lambda +}f(x) = f(\lambda+),$$

and $f$ is continuous at $\lambda.$

(2) Jump discontinuities accumulate at $\lambda$. Let $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ be any increasing and decreasing sequences of points, respectively, both converging to $\lambda$. Since, the sums of the jumps must be bounded by the total variation of $f$, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |f_R(y_k) - f_L(y_k)| < \infty, \\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |f_R(z_k) - f_L(z_k)| < \infty,$$

and $\lim_{k \to \infty} |f_R(y_k) - f_L(y_k)| =  \lim_{k \to \infty} |f_R(z_k) - f_L(z_k)| = 0$.

Thus,

$$f_L(\lambda-) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f_L(y_k) =  \lim_{k \to \infty} f_R(y_k) -  \lim_{k \to \infty} (f_R(y_k) - f_L(y_k)) = f_R(\lambda-), \\ f_L(\lambda+) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f_L(z_k) =  \lim_{k \to \infty} f_R(z_k) -  \lim_{k \to \infty} (f_R(z_k) - f_L(z_k)) = f_R(\lambda+), $$

and

$$f_L(\lambda-) = f_L(\lambda+) = f_R(\lambda+) = f_R(\lambda-).$$

**Original Proof**

By hypothesis, $\tilde{f}$ is continuous at $\lambda$. We must have $f(\lambda-) = f(\lambda+) =\tilde{f}(\lambda)$ when $ f$ is continuous at $\lambda$.

Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $\lambda$. This implies $f(\lambda-) \neq  f(\lambda+) = \tilde{f} (\lambda).$ Since the left-hand limit exists there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $\lambda$ from the left such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $\tilde{f}(\lambda)$.

Hence, there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$  such that for all sufficiently large $n$,

$$|f(x_n) - \tilde{f}(\lambda)| > \epsilon_0.$$

Now choose a sequence of points $(y_n)$ such that $x_n - 1/2^{n} < y_n < x_n.$ Then $y_n \to \lambda$ and $|f(x_n) - \tilde{f}(y_n)| < \epsilon_0/2$ for sufficiently large $n$, since the right-hand limit exists everywhere (and convergence is uniform in a compact neighborhood of $\lambda$).

Thus,

$$|\tilde{f}(y_n) - \tilde{f}(\lambda)| > |f(x_n) - \tilde{f}(\lambda)| - |f(x_n) - \tilde{f}(y_n)| > \epsilon_0/2, $$

which contradicts the continuity of $\tilde{f}$ at $\lambda.$

Comment: Very eloquently written! Thank you!

Comment: @followerofdanu: Thanks. I'm concerned about a potential flaw in my proof. I provided another.

Comment: Could you care to explain why that needs uniform convergence? BTW thank you for caring for this question enough to be careful.

Comment: Because both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are changing. For example if $f(x) = x^2$ and $x_n = n$, $y_n = n + 1/n$ then $|y_n - x_n| < 1/n$ but $|f(x_n) -f(y_n)| = 2 + 1/n^2 \to 2$.  Even though $x_n$ and $y_n$ become arbitrarily close the function values stay apart -- without uniform convergence.  Also the first proof never really used the bounded variation aspect.  Its possible that one can show uniform convergence because of BV, but I was unable to.  I

Comment: Another approach might use the fact that a BV function is the difference of two increasing functions.

Comment: I tried an approach following this hint and posted an answer. @RRL, would you be so kind as to review it?

Comment: Sure. I'll take a look and get back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Following an idea of RRL, I wanted to prove this statement by using the Jordan decomposition, but I found what I think is a simpler way to do it.

We use the following lemma:

$\mathbf{Lemma}$
In the notation of the OP, we have that $\tilde{f}(\lambda+)=f(\lambda+)$ and $\tilde{f}(\lambda-)=f(\lambda-)$ .

$\mathit{Proof}$: Since $f$ only has a countable set of discontinuities, there exist$^{1}$ sequences $\Lambda_{n}$, $\lambda_{n}$ of points of continuity of $f$ such that $\Lambda_{n} \rightarrow \lambda+$ and $\lambda_{n}\rightarrow \lambda-$. By definition, on the set $C$ of points of continuity of $f$, $\tilde{f}|_{C}=f|_{C}$. Thus:

$\tilde{f}(\lambda+)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tilde{f}(\Lambda_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(\Lambda_{n})=f(\lambda+)$

since both limits exist. We can work similarly using $\lambda_{n}$ to get the other claim:

$\tilde{f}(\lambda-)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tilde{f}(\lambda_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(\lambda_{n})=f(\lambda-)$

$\blacksquare$

By the lemma, if for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $ \tilde{f}(\lambda+)=\tilde{f}(\lambda-)$, we also have $f(\lambda+)=f(\lambda-)$ and since $f$ is of bounded variation, it only has jump discontinuities, and thus $\lambda$ is a point of continuity for $f$.

What does this have to do with the Jordan decomposition? I simply noticed that this also works for increasing (or decreasing) functions since it really only needs that a) discontinuities form a countable set and b) there are only jump discontinuities.

1. This follows from the following argument: To find a sequence converging to $\lambda$ from the right, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we pick a point of continuity $\Lambda_{n}$ such that $\Lambda_{n} \in (\lambda, \lambda+1/n)$. This can be done since each of these intervals does not consist only of points of discontinuity since then $f$ would have uncountably many discontinuities. By construction, $\Lambda_{n} \rightarrow \lambda+$. We can work similarly to get $\lambda_{n}$.

Comment: What you have written about the sequences is correct. Given two sequences of continuity points converging to $\lambda$ from left and right, the respective sequences of function values converge to the same limit (using the fact that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous.  In the lemma, however, you can't say that $f(\lambda-) = \tilde{f}(\lambda-)$ because if we knew that we would be done.  Note that $\tilde{f}(\lambda-)$ is the left-hand limit of the right-hand limit.  Nevertheless your sequential argument is useful and needs to be supplemented like case (2) in my proof,

Comment: To prove continuity we have to show that $f(x_n)$ converges to the same value when $x_n \to \lambda$ regardless of the choice for $x_n$.  You proved this if $x_n$ is a continuity point.  If however $x_n$ is a sequence of jump discontinuity points converging to $\lambda$ then you use the second part of my proof which uses bounded variation and shows that the left and right limits at the jumps must get squeezed together.

Comment: Hm, I don't think I understand. To prove continuity of $f$ at $\lambda$ all I need to prove is that the right and left limits agree since this function only has jump discontinuities. Since I know these limits exist, they are the same whatever sequence I choose converging to $\lambda$ from the right or left respectively. So I choose nice enough sequences. I will edit to add the $f(\lambda-) = \tilde{f}(\lambda-)$ proof, which is similar. Maybe there is some confusion because I stated this for functions of bounded variation. That's what I have in my case of interest, not what might be needed.

Comment: @RRL, turns out the whole premise is wrong... Check the edit in the OP.

Comment: That is true. Nothing prevents us from defining the function arbitrarily at a jump location.  If you look at the conclusion of my part (2) you see I only get that the left and right limits agree at $\lambda$. I was operating on the assumption that $f$ is assigned a value somewhere between the left and right limits.   Still you have proved that $f$ has at worst a removable discontinuity at the point.

Comment: I agree. I would like to thank you again for your interest in this question, this conversation about the problem helped me understand what I should do to alleviate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Good work pursuing this to the end.